# ¿Cómo repetir el mismo registro de la base de datos?

Tags: php

Estoy realizando pruebas sobre categorías de productos y artículos, limitando el diseño de la plantilla `HTML & CSS` es decir calcular que espacios tomar para visualizar una estructura correcta de la plantilla.

> Para ello necesito mostrar una cierta cantidad de productos.

Pero solo tengo un solo registro en la base de datos, quiero evitar hacer varios registros en la base de datos debido a que solo es una prueba.

Entonces como puedo mostrar varias veces el mismo registro, mostrar el mismo producto a una cierta cantidad ya sea 10, 20, 50 etc.

**Diseño de la base de datos**

```
ID               TITLE               IMAGE               DETAL           URL
1          New notice globel       globel.png         The globe       new-globe
```

> ACTUALIZACIÓN

```
<?php

function registro(){
    global $con;
    $sql = "Select * from notice where id and active='1' order by id ASC limit 50";
    $rows = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $new_notice = mysqli_num_rows($rows);

    if($new_notice==0){
        echo"No hay noticias";
    }else{
        while ($new = mysqli_fetch_array($rows)) {
            echo'<div id="cont-items">
                       <a href="'.$new['url'].'"><img src="'.$new['image'].'" alt="" /></a>
            ';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: como los estas cargando? tal vez se pueda hacer algo desde el lenguaje?

Comment: @gbianchi actualice mi pregunta, normalmente los registros los nuestros de esa manera.

Comment: puedes hacer un ciclo con un for por ejemplo y repetir las veces que quieras el resultado que te trae la consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente hazle un for al echo adentro del while

```
for ($i=0; $i<50; $i++) {
  echo'<div id="cont-items"><a href="'.$new['url'].'"><img src="'.$new['image'].'" alt="" /></a>';
}
```